# C++ - Inherit from reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

I would like the class A to inherit from the class B without A having is own instantiation of B

The idea would be to create an B object on the heap (using B new) and give the pointer to A.
A would afterwards use this object to solve inheritance.

This is an example of what I would like to do:

```
B* b = new B();
b->myBmethode();
{
  A(b);
  A.myBmethode();
} // A destroyed
b->myBmethode();
delete b;
```

Comment: This is quite confusing.

Comment: Instead of telling us about the mechanism you've thought up, perhaps you could tell us about the problem you're really trying to solve. My guess is there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You don't inherit from objects, or from references to them: you inherit from *classes,* and the mechanisms for doing that are already defined: you can't add to them. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: my question was, is a 'reference to a class' a valid class from witch you could inherit

Comment: The question makes sense, it just isn't C++. This is closer to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible (if I understood your question correctly).

3.7.5

> The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and
>   array elements is that of their complete object

Comment: I understand that, that's why i would like the subobject to be allocated on the heap (using new) rater then on the stack (in order for them to have a longer lifespam)

Comment: @Amxx: Subobjects cannot have a longer lifetime than their complete object. Did you really understand what the quote is saying?

Comment: subobjects are allocated with the main objects, therefor there lifespan is linked.

What i try to achieve here would be for the subobject to be a reference, therefore however the reference would be destroyed with main object, sur subobject behind the reference would still be working

Comment: @Amxx: A subobject generally refers to a data member of a class or base class. What you are referring to is *not* a subobject. Also, once any references to the object go out of scope, there is no way to access the object anymore.

Comment: @Amxx,  use composition rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If B was created outside of A, B won't be deleted automatically after A get deleted,unless u do it explicitly,

Create an interface IA, let both A and B implement that interface. For B, just delegate all the real implementation to B.

The lifecycle of B depend on your design. When would u like it to be destroyed? You can also make B singleton if it make sense.

```
class IA {
  virtual doA() = 0;
}

class A: public IA {
   virtual doA();
}

class B: public IA {    
B(A&a);    
virtual doA(){
   a.doA();
}
private:
   A&a;
}

//init
A* a = A::getInstance();
B *b = new(*a) ;
b->doA();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from a reference, but with something like this you can get half-way there:

```
#include<functional>
...
struct A : std::reference_wrapper<B>{
// using std::reference_wrapper<B>::reference_wrapper; // inherit constructor
};
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper